# Can't mount disks

Tags: mount, hard-disk, kali-linux, disk

I have a Windows 8 / Ubuntu dual boot system.

When I open kali, I can't see any of the hard disk partitions. I receive the following error message:

> Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/root/windows:
>   Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,
>
> nodev,nosuid,uid=0,gid=0,dmask=0077,
>
> fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/root/windows"'
>
> exited with non-zero exit status 14:
>
> Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
>
> Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
>
> The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please
>
> resume and shutdown Windows fully
>
> (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
>
> read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

My /etc/fstab file is

> root@joe:/etc# cat fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=8b18065b-bf87-4901-bf63-5160373ec384 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

I have not hibernated Windows, I made a full shutdown. Still, I get this error message:

dskchk in Windows:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
>
> (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.
>
> 16384_none_1fac8b4435f61ead>dskchk
>
> 'dskchk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.
>
> 16384_none_1fac8b4435f61ead>chkdsk
>
> The type of the file system is NTFS.
>
> Volume label is windows.
>
> WARNING!  F parameter not specified.
>
> Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.
>
> Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
>
> 457216 file records processed.
>
> File verification completed.
>
> 1000 large file records processed.
>
> 0 bad file records processed.
>
> Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
>
> 535184 index entries processed.
>
> Index verification completed.
>
> 0 unindexed files scanned.
>
> 0 unindexed files recovered.
>
> Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
>   Security descriptor verification completed.
>
> 38985 data files processed.
>   CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
>
> 39528320 USN bytes processed.
>
> Usn Journal verification completed.
>   The Volume Bitmap is incorrect.
>   Windows has checked the file system and found problems.
>   Please run chkdsk /scan to find the problems and queue them for repair.
>
> 102265855 KB total disk space.
>
> 83621268 KB in 209367 files.
>
> 147684 KB in 38986 indexes.
>
> ```
>     0 KB in bad sectors.
> ```
>
> 570671 KB in use by the system.
>
> ```
> 65536 KB occupied by the log file.
> ```
>
> 17926232 KB available on disk.
>
> ```
>  4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
> ```
>
> 25566463 total allocation units on disk.
>
> 4481558 allocation units available on disk.
>
> C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.
>
> 16384_none_1fac8b4435f61

Chkdsk/scan result:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
>   (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.
>   16384_none_1fac8b4435f61ead>chkdsk/scan
>   The type of the file system is NTFS.
>    Volume label is w.
>
> Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
>
> 457216 file records processed.
>
> File verification completed.
>
> 1000 large file records processed.
>
> 0 bad file records processed.
>
> Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
>
> 535166 index entries processed.
>
> Index verification completed.
>
> 0 unindexed files scanned.
>
> 0 unindexed files recovered.
>
> Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
>
> Security descriptor verification completed.
>
> 38976 data files processed.
>
> CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
>
> 39632264 USN bytes processed.
>
> Usn Journal verification completed.
>
> Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
>
> No further action is required.
>
> 102265855 KB total disk space.
>
> 83435980 KB in 209375 files.
>
> ```
> 147684 KB in 38977 indexes.
>
>
>     0 KB in bad sectors.
>
> 570735 KB in use by the system.
>
>  65536 KB occupied by the log file.
> ```
>
> 18111456 KB available on disk.
>
> ```
>   4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
> ```
>
> 25566463 total allocation units on disk.
>
> 4527864 allocation units available on disk.
>
> C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.
>
> 16384_none_1fac8b4435f61ead>

Comment: run chkdsk in windows

Comment: @paul the chkdsk result is update . Look up

Comment: Windows has checked the file system and found problems. Please run chkdsk /scan to find the problems and queue them for repair.

Comment: How to queue and repair

Comment: As windows said: "run chkdsk /scan". Before try "chkdsk /f"

Comment: The result is updated . Can i reboot and check now ?

Comment: For any more recent issues, Windows does have a "feature" where shutting down now hibernates some items before shutting down.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is already in the error message you offer:

> Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Even if you "fully" poweroff or shutdown the computer, Windows may hilbernate. So just mount the Windows partition as read only (add `ro` flag in the item of the Windows partition in your /etc/fstab file).

PS there're already many questions being asked about this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/280530/how-do-i-mount-a-hibernated-partition-with-windows-8-in-ubuntu

Comment: I cant mount  my drives ( C, D,E )

Comment: @Joe_Vj_95 you need to know the device name of (C, D, E) in Ubuntu Linux, should be like `/dev/sdaX`. Say the C disk in WIn8 is `/dev/sda1`, you can mount it manually by `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda1 /mnt/C`

Comment: How can i find the device name ?

Comment: I need to mount it in read write mode

Comment: You can use the output of `lsblk` or `df` to 'guess' the device name. Sorry I can't help if you want it be read write. It's Windows's problem, perhaps you need to config your Windows somehow.